# Replace NA with row mean in R for subset

Tags: r, for-loop, replace, row

I have a questionnaire dataset with three sub-scales. If a sub-scale is missing data in a row, I want to replace that specific column value with the row mean.

For the example data, I want to act as if there is only one subscale, composed of c1 and c2.

```
c1 <- c(1,2,3,NA,4)
c2 <- c(1,NA,45,4,100)
c3 <- c(NA,2,3,9,NA)
data <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3)
```

I have tried several things, however those didn't work.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data[,c(1,2)])){
  for(n in 1:ncol(data[,c(1,2)])){
    if(is.na(data[,c(1,2)][i,n])){
      data[,c(1,2)][i,n]  <-  mean(t(data[,c(1,2)][i,]), na.rm = T)}}} 

#Version 2
k <- which(is.na(data[,c(1,2)]),arr.ind=TRUE) 
data[,c(1,2)][[k]] <- rowMeans(data[,c(1,2)],na.rm=TRUE)[k[,1]]
```

For Version 1, all values in the columns with one NA were replaced. For Version 2, it showed an error message.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

PS: This is a coding question (not about statistical appropriateness of the method).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using **dplyr** :

```
data <- data %>% 
mutate(c1 = ifelse(is.na(c1),rowMeans(data[row_number(),], na.rm = T),c1),
       c2 = ifelse(is.na(c2),rowMeans(data[row_number(),], na.rm = T),c2),
       c3 = ifelse(is.na(c3),rowMeans(data[row_number(),], na.rm = T),c3))
```

Comment: Hello! How do I do this for a big amount of columns + how can I limit the rows across which the mean will be calculated? (for the data example, only c1 and c2 should be included in rowMeans)

Comment: I see an issue here: if you want to impute the value for the c2 or c1 column, you will not be able to get the mean of c1 and c2.

For a big amount of column, you can create a function :
`MyFunction <- function(table){
for(i in ncol(table)){
 table <- table %>%
     mutate(paste("c",i) = ifelse(...))
  }
}`